# Convert HTML Page to Plain Text using PHP

Tags: php, strip-tags

To be more precise, i need to be able to Strip HTML Tags as nice as this script does: zubrag.com/tools/html-tags-stripper.php

I need to be able to do this on my localhost (xampp server) with any url, but for now i would like to use this url to strip tags from, as this is as messiest it can get: http://static.anaf.ro/static/10/Timis/Timis.htm

**What I do have**, doesn't work and I don't know why or how to fix it.
Here's were the code comes from: nadeausoftware.com/articles/2007/09/php_tip_how_strip_html_tags_web_page

I've added this line to the code, but it still won't work ...

```
$text = file_get_contents('http://static.anaf.ro/static/10/Timis/Timis.htm');
```

Below is the raw code (note that the original code doesn't have the line from above. That line  was added by me)

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2008, David R. Nadeau, NadeauSoftware.com.
 * All rights reserved.
 * See:
 *  http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2007/09/php_tip_how_strip_html_tags_web_page
 */


$text = file_get_contents('http://static.anaf.ro/static/10/Timis/Timis.htm');

function strip_html_tags( $text )
{
    // PHP's strip_tags() function will remove tags, but it
    // doesn't remove scripts, styles, and other unwanted
    // invisible text between tags.  Also, as a prelude to
    // tokenizing the text, we need to insure that when
    // block-level tags (such as <p> or <div>) are removed,
    // neighboring words aren't joined.
    $text = preg_replace(
        array(
            // Remove invisible content
            '@<head[^>]*?>.*?</head>@siu',
            '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siu',
            '@<script[^>]*?.*?</script>@siu',
            '@<object[^>]*?.*?</object>@siu',
            '@<embed[^>]*?.*?</embed>@siu',
            '@<applet[^>]*?.*?</applet>@siu',
            '@<noframes[^>]*?.*?</noframes>@siu',
            '@<noscript[^>]*?.*?</noscript>@siu',
            '@<noembed[^>]*?.*?</noembed>@siu',

            // Add line breaks before & after blocks
            '@<((br)|(hr))@iu',
            '@</?((address)|(blockquote)|(center)|(del))@iu',
            '@</?((div)|(h[1-9])|(ins)|(isindex)|(p)|(pre))@iu',
            '@</?((dir)|(dl)|(dt)|(dd)|(li)|(menu)|(ol)|(ul))@iu',
            '@</?((table)|(th)|(td)|(caption))@iu',
            '@</?((form)|(button)|(fieldset)|(legend)|(input))@iu',
            '@</?((label)|(select)|(optgroup)|(option)|(textarea))@iu',
            '@</?((frameset)|(frame)|(iframe))@iu',
        ),
        array(
            ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',
            "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0",
            "\n\$0", "\n\$0",
        ),
        $text );

    // Remove all remaining tags and comments and return.
    echo strip_tags( $text );
}
```

Comment: So, where's the call `strip_html_tags( $your_text )` and what's the result of it? Also, do you uderstand that you showed us just a function definition? And didn't show function call?

Comment: i forgot to mention i don't know php .. i'm just a newbie. the html page to convert into plain text would be the link included in the question which is http://static.anaf.ro/static/10/Timis/Timis.htm other than that i don't know what should be included in the code..this is actually what i am hoping to get help with ... some dirrections at least

Comment: Then I advise you to read manual - http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine, but the regex from the link in your post doesn't work. It doesn't return the right charset, so try this:

```
function strip_html_tags( $text )
{
    $text = preg_replace(
        array(
          // Remove invisible content
            '@<head[^>]*?>.*?</head>@siu',
            '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siu',
            '@<script[^>]*?.*?</script>@siu',
            '@<object[^>]*?.*?</object>@siu',
            '@<embed[^>]*?.*?</embed>@siu',
            '@<applet[^>]*?.*?</applet>@siu',
            '@<noframes[^>]*?.*?</noframes>@siu',
            '@<noscript[^>]*?.*?</noscript>@siu',
            '@<noembed[^>]*?.*?</noembed>@siu',
          // Add line breaks before and after blocks
            '@</?((address)|(blockquote)|(center)|(del))@iu',
            '@</?((div)|(h[1-9])|(ins)|(isindex)|(p)|(pre))@iu',
            '@</?((dir)|(dl)|(dt)|(dd)|(li)|(menu)|(ol)|(ul))@iu',
            '@</?((table)|(th)|(td)|(caption))@iu',
            '@</?((form)|(button)|(fieldset)|(legend)|(input))@iu',
            '@</?((label)|(select)|(optgroup)|(option)|(textarea))@iu',
            '@</?((frameset)|(frame)|(iframe))@iu',
        ),
        array(
            ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',
            "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0",
            "\n\$0", "\n\$0",
        ),
        $text );
    return strip_tags( $text );
}

/* Read an HTML file */
$raw_text =  file_get_contents('http://static.anaf.ro/static/10/Timis/Timis.htm');

/* Get the file's character encoding from a <meta> tag */
preg_match("/<meta[^>]+charset=['\"]?(.*?)['\"]?[\/\s>]/i", $raw_text, $matches );
$encoding = $matches[1];

/* Convert to UTF-8 before doing anything else */
$utf8_text = iconv( $encoding, "utf-8", $raw_text );

/* Strip HTML tags and invisible text */
$utf8_text = strip_html_tags( $utf8_text );

/* Decode HTML entities */
$utf8_text = html_entity_decode( $utf8_text, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8" );
echo $utf8_text;
```

**What I've changed:**

To get the right charset I simply replaced this

```
/* Get the file's character encoding from a <meta> tag */
preg_match( '@<meta\s+http-equiv="Content-Type"\s+content="([\w/]+)(;\s+charset=([^\s"]+))?@i', $raw_text, $matches );
$encoding = $matches[3];
```

with this

```
preg_match("/<meta[^>]+charset=['\"]?(.*?)['\"]?[\/\s>]/i", $raw_text, $matches );
$encoding = $matches[1];
```

EDIT 1:
Guess the script from the website does have some problems with stripping the tags from the URL you provided. It shows a lot of Â's. I guess the best way to strip tags is simply strip everything between an opening < and the first closing >. But I don't have any idea for a regex at the moment, maybe google could help :)

Comment: nice fix ... can we add some line breaks to this to make the content readable ? P.S sorry for delayed reply, i was trying to learn functions :)

Comment: @Erik Just want to say thank you!!! Literally the whole day for me. Almost gave up at work lol